# How to assign a sheet name when exporting from R

Tags: r

I am using the below code to export a data frame from RStudio to excel file. I want to define the sheet name while exporting however despite of writing the correct code the exported file contains the default sheet name "Sheet1". Seeking help where I am going wrong? I am using "xlsx" package.

```r
write.xlsx(SLIDE6FVOLT, "C:\\Users\\I0510906\\Desktop\\RAuto\\SLIDE6FVOLT.xlsx", 
    sheetname = "SLIDE6FVOLT", colnames = TRUE, rownames = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter is called `sheetName=` not `sheetname=`

Comment: Thank you so much Oliver. Such a silly thing and I didn't spot it. Many many thanks again.